# Php filtering content wrong way

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to filter content depending on if a field has the value of 'copyclearance'. It is filtering but instead of showing the content with a value of 'copyclearance' it is hiding it and displaying the others. How do I alternate this so that it only displays the content with a value of 'copyclearance'.

```
<?php while(has_sub_field('team_profile')): 
        $category = get_sub_field('category');
        if($category!='copyclearance'){ ?>
        <li class="col-lg-3 teamProfile">
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('user_image'); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
            <h2><?php the_sub_field('profile_name'); ?></h2>
            <p class="jobTitle"><?php the_sub_field('category'); ?></p>
            <p><?php the_sub_field('bio'); ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php } 
    endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: change if($category!='copyclearance') to if($category=='copyclearance')

Comment: If the logic is wrong implemented, it's always PHP's fault :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change

```
if($category!='copyclearance')
```

to

```
if($category=='copyclearance')
```